# Why doesn't my custom component update when I change properties with setAttribute?

Tags: aframe

I think I don't quite understand how components and entities work.
I'm using the box component that appears in the a-frame help (https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#example-box-component), and I want to modify a property. When doing so, I thought that the update would be activated but it does nothing. In fact the oldData is always empty and never enters in the update option (except for the first time):

```
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("box", {
     ...
  }
</script>

<a-scene> </a-scene>

<script>
  const gScene = document.querySelector("a-scene");

  var camara = document.querySelector("[camera]");
  camara.setAttribute("position", { x: 0, y: 0, z: 10 });

  var p00 = document.createElement("a-entity");
  p00.setAttribute("box", { width: 1, height: 1, depth: 1, color: "#f00" });
  gScene.appendChild(p00);

  p00.setAttribute("height", 3);
  p00.setAttribute("color", "#00f");
</script>
```

First part of the code plot a red box with 1x1x1 dimension. But when I change the height or color attribute, don't do anything. What I have to do to fire the update?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the `box` attribute - `setAttribute("height", XXX)` will trigger an update in the `height` component.

If `color` is in the `box` schema, then:

```
 // this updates the color property of the box attribute,
 // triggering "update" in the "box" component
 p00.setAttribute("box", "color", "red")
 
 // this update the height attribute,
 // triggering "update" in the "height" component
 p00.setAttribute("height", "10");
```